# Trying to get cookies when I visit a website

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest, webrequest, httpwebresponse

I am trying to visit a website, to get cookies to store for later use, but when I create the webrequest, it doesn't send back any cookies, but if I view it in a browser, the request sends cookies.

The code I am using to create the request:

```
        'get the cookie for the post request !important
        Dim req As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/index.html"), HttpWebRequest)
        req.Method = "GET"
        req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
        req.Host = "www.dailymail.com"
        req.CookieContainer = tmpcookie


        'get the cookie.
        Dim postcookie = DirectCast(req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        tmpcookie.Add(postcookie.Cookies)
```

In my fiddler, when I visit the website I get the following information:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXl39.png)

And when I create the request via webrequests, I get the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT67T.png)

As you can see, no cookies are being sent. How can I get the cookies?

Comment: Notice that the browser sent a User-Agent and your webrequest did not have its [`UserAgent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent(v=vs.110).aspx) set. It *might* make a difference.

Comment: Still not receiving any cookies, it's just bypassing my for loop for the cookies,